# Не получается создать кнопку в Python Kivy для добавления дополнительного BoxLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Уважаемые Знатоки! Помогите сделать кнопку, которая бы добавляла еще экземпляр BoxLayout помимо существующих, в Python, в Kivy да и вообще в программировании новичок, поэтому не судите строго, пытался сам найти в документации, но увы ничего не получилось, заранее большущее спасибо!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
 
class MyApp(App):


    def build(self):
    #Создаем первый экземпляр BoxLayout

        bl = BoxLayout()
        bl_1 = BoxLayout()

        bl_1.add_widget(TextInput())
        bl_1.add_widget(TextInput())
        bl_1.add_widget(Button(text = 'V', on_press = self.btn_press))

        bl.add_widget(bl_1)

        return bl


    def btn_press(self, instance):
    # Создаем кнопку для добавления дополнительного BoxLayout
        bl = BoxLayout()
        bl_1 = BoxLayout()

        bl_1.add_widget(TextInput())
        bl_1.add_widget(TextInput())
        bl_1.add_widget(Button(text = 'V', on_press = self.btn_press))

        bl.add_widget(bl_1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто, вам нужно было сохранить в переменную `bl = BoxLayout()` из `build`, т.к. он является основой, на котором остальные виджеты и компоновщики находятся, для удобства понимания назвал его `main_layout`, и привязать к экземпляру объекта `MyApp` через `self`.

После чего, было просто к нему обратиться в `btn_press`

Попробуйте:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Создаем первый экземпляр BoxLayout
        self.main_layout = BoxLayout()

        bl_1 = BoxLayout()
        bl_1.add_widget(TextInput())
        bl_1.add_widget(TextInput())
        bl_1.add_widget(Button(text='V', on_press=self.btn_press))

        self.main_layout.add_widget(bl_1)

        return self.main_layout

    def btn_press(self, instance):
        # Создаем кнопку для добавления дополнительного BoxLayout
        bl_1 = BoxLayout()
        bl_1.add_widget(TextInput())
        bl_1.add_widget(TextInput())
        bl_1.add_widget(Button(text='V', on_press=self.btn_press))

        self.main_layout.add_widget(bl_1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогли!

Comment: @АЛЕКСЕЙКорин, пожалуйста :)